# extract column from multiple tab delimited file using perl

Tags: perl

File 1, 2 and 3 has many column, I need to extract specific column from specific files like first 3 column from file 1, 3rd column from file 2 and 3 rd column from file 3 and save it has another file.
Note: File names are not fixed but the column to be extract are fixed

```
my @file = <> 
my @OA = ();

foreach my $line (@file)
{
        my @temp = split(/\t/, trim($_));
        push(@OA, $temp[0] . "\t" . $temp[1] . "\t" . $temp[2] . "\n");
}
```

This will help for extracting data from single file.
can anyone help me to extend this to get the column from file 2 and so on.

Thanks,
N.

Comment: how do you select the required column based on the file name?

Comment: Where do you need to extract the column?  Do you want to write it to standard output, or save the values in an array, or what?  You should not use `@file = <>;` because it reads all of all the files into memory (which wastes memory), and there's no way to tell where file 1 ended or where file 2 ended.  Are the columns you're interested in fixed or can it vary depending on which files you're processing?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, column i need to extract is fixed and i need to save it has new file

Comment: @Wordzilla, i need to select column based on file name

Comment: Are the file names fixed too, or do you specify them on the command line?  And please add the information to your question, rather than making comments.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, file name will differ not fixed

Comment: Please pay attention! Edit your comments into the question (you can do that) and don't make them into comments.  You should probably design your system to process the given columns from a named file.  In fact, there's a standard program on Unix that does that: [`cut`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html).  You could also trivially use `awk` for the task.  Since you know how to do it, approximately, for one file, extending to three should be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a stub of how you could interact with multiple file handles in parallel:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @fhs;
for my $file (qw(file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt)) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    push @fhs, $fh;
}

while (! grep eof, @fhs) {
    my @lines = map {scalar <$_>} @fhs;
    chomp @lines;

    print "fh0 = $lines[0]\n";
    print "fh1 = $lines[1]\n";
    print "fh2 = $lines[2]\n";
}
```